# How do I deploy Firebase cloud function changes to firebase instance?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have just deployed my first Firebase could function with this command
firebase deploy --only functions

and then I found some mistakes in the function code. I have corrected the mistakes in index.js and now how do I deploy the changes to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure you saved your changes in the `index.js` file (CMD + S in Visual Studio in Mac). Then open terminal -> `firebase deploy` in your parent map where the `index.js` file is located. It will take about a minute.

Comment: @Eddi FYI, deploy --only functions will also work, of course

Comment: do I need to reinitialize firebase in that directory and reinstall packages in that directory or just by saving changes and running deploy --only functions will work fine? Kindly help.